# See Perforce Command-History per User

Tags: perforce, obliterate

We are trying to figure out a mysterious p4 obliterate command.
Is there a way to see the command history at the server, from which client was it issued, etc? Does the history information being stored some where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can check your server log. It depends on what OS your server is running on, and how it was set up. I would check to see if P4LOG is set on your server, or on the command line you used to start the server. If not check the P4ROOT dir.

Answer (score 0):

Like aflat stated you would want to check the P4LOG if it is setup. The entry for p4 obliterate may be a bit hard to identify so you might want to take a look at the following URL http://kb.perforce.com/article/1107 to get an idea of what to look for.

If your server does not have P4LOG set you could also try looking at the actual Perforce journal file, which keeps track of all transactions in Perforce. But I must warn you that accessing the journal file directly is high risk and should not be done without contacting Perforce support first.